# Altium: Connecting routes through different layers

Tags: pcb, altium, routing, layers

I know how to route and create vias to connect the track from one layer to the next (i.e. layer A to B then to C). But is it possible to connect tracks from one layer to a specified layer directly without having to go through the intermediate layers (i.e. layer A to C)? If so how?

Comment: which version of Altium are u using?

Comment: A via from layer A to layer C must pass through layer B, but won't connect to anything on layer B (unless you want it to).  Unless you are using blind vias, a via will pass through all layers of the board.

Comment: Altium V13 @SanjeevKumar

Answer (score 1):

Vias don't connect to the internal plans unless you have connected it to the net.

Example :

Stack Up :  Top layer - Signal Layer - Internal Plane - Bottom Layer

Let's Say Internal Plane is GND. If you place a via from top to bottom which is connected to a Net_17, then clearance around the via will be seen in INTERNAL PLANE. Hence the via will not be connected in any of the internal layers. Just Top and Bottom. Altium is very powerful  and sophisticated tool. Just set the Design rules accordingly.

You need to set Clearance rule in the Design Rules

[image]

As you can see the via is from top to bottom and connected to GND net and GND is the internal plane. The major blue you see is the polygon fill on the bottom layer and polygon is connected to VCC. Clearance is noticeable around the via which can be customized through Clearance rule

Answer (score 0):

Actually layer switching (by "+" and "-") works for visible signal layers. So, you can disable your internal signal layers through "View Configurations" window while you're routing needed layers, and then return view configuration to its normal state.

[image: View configuration window]